# ABR File to JPEG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, brush

I have collected over the years a huge collection of brushes, 3gb worth, that I would like a way I can export them out and possibly make a database file of them.  However, I am unsure how to export an .abr file to jpeg so I can have a screenshot of brushes.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick Google search gave me a number of options.

Here is one example of software that seems like a good fit for your needs called [abrMate](https://web.archive.org/web/20181211162231/http://www.texturemate.com/abrMate)

Answer (score 2):

Do you *really* use 3GB of brush files? *Really?* I used to collect a great many things like this and then I realized 99% of the time it was much faster to just recreate any overly-specialized brush, or Google, then download. Rather than trying to sort through lists of files.

Johannes link is for Windows only.... [**Here's a link to an .abr viewer**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/abrviewer/) for any platform